# Read violation when passing object as parameter using Python and ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I'm in the process of trying to expose an existing hardware API written in C++ to Python, using ctypes.  The existing API creates a communications socket object and then passes that by reference to other components which use it to communicate with the hardware.  There's a lot of extraneous detail in the full API, so I have stripped it back to a simple example which exhibits the same failure I'm seeing in the full system.  I'm not an expert programmer, and completely new to Python, so I suspect I'm doing something silly.  The native C++ code comprises the following:

A **Comms** class

comms.h

```
#ifndef COMMS_H
#define COMMS_H

#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::uint32_t;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Comms
{
public:
    Comms();
    void getStatus();

private:
    string   m_addr;
    uint32_t m_port;
};

#endif // COMMS_H
```

comms.cpp

```
#include "comms.h"

Comms::Comms()
{
    m_addr = "192.168.2.1";
    m_port = 5000;
}

void Comms::getStatus()
{
    cout << "Comms object handle is " << this << endl;
    cout << "Comms address is " << m_addr << endl;
    cout << "Comms port is " << m_port << endl << endl;
}

// Extern methods for Python binding via ctypes
extern "C" {
    Comms* Comms_new(){ return new Comms(); }
    void Comms_getStatus(Comms* comms){ comms->getStatus(); }
}
```

A **UserApp** class, which takes a parameter of type **Comms**, passed by reference.

userapp.h

```
#ifndef USERAPP_H
#define USERAPP_H

#include <iostream>
#include "../Comms/comms.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class UserApp
{
public:
    UserApp(Comms *theComms);
};

#endif // USERAPP_H
```

userapp.cpp

```
#include "userapp.h"

UserApp::UserApp(Comms *theComms)
{    
    cout << "New UserApp created, Comms object passed by reference" << endl;
    cout << "UserApp handle is " << this << endl;
    cout << "Comms handle is " << theComms << endl << endl;
    theComms->getStatus();
}

// Extern methods for Python binding via ctypes
extern "C" {
    UserApp* UserApp_new(Comms *theComms){ return new UserApp(theComms); }
}
```

In C++ this all works fine, I have a simple main.cpp (running in Qt) with one instantiation of each class...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Comms myComms;
    myComms.getStatus();

    UserApp myUserApp(&myComms);

    return a.exec();
}
```

....and the output is consistent with what I'd expect:

```
Comms object handle is 0x28fea0
Comms address is 192.168.2.1
Comms port is 5000

New UserApp created, Comms object passed by reference
UserApp handle is 0x28fe9f
Comms handle is 0x28fea0

Comms object handle is 0x28fea0
Comms address is 192.168.2.1
Comms port is 5000
```

To bind all this to Python, I've created DLLs based on the above and written the following classes to mirror the C++ versions:

Comms.py

```
from ctypes import *
import os
commsLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("Comms.dll")

class Comms(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = commsLib.Comms_new()  

    def getStatus(self):
        commsLib.Comms_getStatus(self.obj)
```

UserApp.py

```
from ctypes import *
import os

UserAppLib = cdll.LoadLibrary("UserApp.dll")

class UserApp(object):
    def __init__(self, comms):
        self.obj = UserAppLib.UserApp_new(comms)
```

And my Python top level is as follows, again trying to mirror what I did in C++:

```
from ctypes import *

from Comms  import Comms
from UserApp import UserApp

myComms = Comms()
myComms.getStatus()

myUserApp = UserApp(py_object(myComms))
```

The Python output is as follows.  I can see that creation of myComms looks OK, but that when I attempt to pass this to myUserApp, the myComms object references don't tie up, and the code throws an access violation OSError.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Comms object handle is 0x183048
Comms address is 192.168.2.1
Comms port is 5000

New UserApp created, Comms object passed by reference
UserApp handle is 0x183078
Comms handle is 0x568bb0

Comms object handle is 0x568bb0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper_api_UnitTest.py", line 9, in <module>
    myUserApp = UserApp(py_object(myComms))
  File "c:\Temp\ctypes_test\python\UserApp.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.obj = UserAppLib.UserApp_new(comms)    
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFF6
```